# Centralized function to delegate form onSubmit to Flux Actions

Tags: javascript, forms, events, reactjs, flux

I have a react app with many different forms I'm looking to not have to write the same code over and over for each form, and I'm looking for a simple way to centralize the `onSubmit()` handlers for all forms. From a central location I can trigger the specific Flux action that will trigger an ajax call.

I'm picturing one function that takes care of all form requests.

```
function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var $elm = $(event.target)
  var d = {}
  d.method = $elm.attr('method')
  d.action = $elm.attr('action')
  d.data = $elm.serialize()
  console.log(d)
}
```

From here I can check the `action` and `method` and make a switch for each possibility.

Does this make sense within the Flux architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will anyway need to collect data from specific components, so you will have to write individual functions for it, but the rest of task like sending an `action` can be done in the `onSubmit` function of a parent component. So delegate all `onSubmit` events in children components with data to the `onSubmit` functions of parent component via `props`.

You can also add an `identifier` like we do as `constants` in dispatchers, to identify particular `onSubmit` event and then in parent component use switch statements to send particular actions based on `identifier`.

If there's a use case, I guess it makes sense.